# How can I make particles move like a square in Unity?

Tags: unity

I would like to implement something like this in Unity:

[image]

I searched for how to implement such a functionality but only found stuff for circles which does not work with box shapes. How can I implement this?

Comment: Create a Particle System, set it to world space, and create an animation that moves the Particle System in a square shape

Comment: Hmm. That seems good in the first sight but mixing animations with the particle system might not be a good idea maybe? Also which property would I animate?

Comment: What concrete evidence do you have that demonstrates it would be not a good idea? What property controls location in space other than transform.position?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I tried what you said and I believe it would have worked if I had more experience with Unity. I now took the tip of Philipp but I will try your solution aswell :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a particle system as a child of the sprite. Set it to create particles in world space, so spawned particles don't move when the system itself moves. That creates a "trail" effect like you see here.

Then create a looping [timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.timeline@1.5/manual/index.html) to create an animation to move the position of the particle effect around the sprite in any paths you want. A timeline can also be used to control any other settings of particle effects over time, which allows you to sequence some really neat choreographies for them.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed :)